# Column not allowed here PL/SQL error from java

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to make an insert query into PL/SQL database .

This is my param declaration :
I am getting error:

> column not allowed here

.

```
DECLARE 
  paramPartnerId hra_walgreens_integration.partner_id%type := ?;
  paramUserId hra_walgreens_integration.user_id%type := ?;
  paramAccessToken hra_walgreens_integration.access_token%type := ?;
  paramRefreshToken hra_walgreens_integration.refresh_token%type := ?;
  paramInput hra_walgreens_integration.json_input%type := ?;
  paramATokenExpiry hra_walgreens_integration.access_token_expiry%type := ?;
  paramRTokenExpiry hra_walgreens_integration.refresh_token_expiry%type := ?;
  paramResponse hra_walgreens_integration.response%type := ?;
  paramAddTime hra_walgreens_integration.add_time%type := ?;
  paramTranId hra_walgreens_integration.transaction_id%type := ?;
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO hra_walgreens_integration (partner_id, user_id, access_token, refresh_token, json_input,access_token_expiry,refresh_token_expiry ,response, add_Time,transaction_id) 
  VALUES (paramPartnerId, paramUserId, paramAccessToken, paramRefreshToken, paramInput, TO_DATE(paramATokenExpiry,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'), TO_DATE(paramRTokenExpiry,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'), paramResponse, paramAdd_time, paramTranId);
END;
```

Comment: Why are you using an anonymous PL/SQL block here?  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable name is `paramAddTime` but your insert statement references `paramAdd_time`.  Change it to:

```
DECLARE 
  paramPartnerId hra_walgreens_integration.partner_id%type := ?;
  paramUserId hra_walgreens_integration.user_id%type := ?;
  paramAccessToken hra_walgreens_integration.access_token%type := ?;
  paramRefreshToken hra_walgreens_integration.refresh_token%type := ?;
  paramInput hra_walgreens_integration.json_input%type := ?;
  paramATokenExpiry hra_walgreens_integration.access_token_expiry%type := ?;
  paramRTokenExpiry hra_walgreens_integration.refresh_token_expiry%type := ?;
  paramResponse hra_walgreens_integration.response%type := ?;
  paramAddTime hra_walgreens_integration.add_time%type := ?;
  paramTranId hra_walgreens_integration.transaction_id%type := ?;
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO hra_walgreens_integration (partner_id, user_id, access_token, refresh_token, json_input,access_token_expiry,refresh_token_expiry ,response, add_Time,transaction_id) 
  VALUES (paramPartnerId, paramUserId, paramAccessToken, paramRefreshToken, paramInput, TO_DATE(paramATokenExpiry,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'), TO_DATE(paramRTokenExpiry,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'), paramResponse, paramAddTime, paramTranId);
END;
```